# Flutter Combine two Stream<List<Object>> into a single stream and Provide it

Tags: flutter, dart

I am implementing my current solution as an Rx.combineLatest, because the following below doesn't work and I would like to understand why.

I am combining two `Stream<List<Object>>` into a single stream, then using `provider` to provide throughout.

I'm using the `StreamGroup` code just like the implementation documentation:

```dart
      Stream<List<AttendeeData>> merge(Iterable<Stream<List<AttendeeData>>> streams) {
        var group = StreamGroup<List<AttendeeData>>();
        streams.forEach(group.add);
        group.close();
        return group.stream;
      }

      List<Stream<List<AttendeeData>>> listStream = [];
      Stream<List<AttendeeData>?>? streamGroup;

      userData.facilities.forEach((key, value) async {
        listStream.add(DatabaseStreamingService(facility: key, uid: user.uid).getAllAttendeesPickUpUsers);
      });

      streamGroup = merge(listStream);

      return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<List<AttendeeData>?>.value(
            value: streamGroup,
            initialData: null,
          ),
        ],...
```

I have lists on both streams, can get them independently, and if I switch the order of them, I get the first one, not the second one.

Note: I have a solution, so I'm not asking for alternatives. I'm just failing to understand why this isn't functioning as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Rx.merge` from `rxdart`? There are lots of helpful `Stream` utilities in there.

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class AttendeeData {
  final String name;

  AttendeeData({required this.name});
}

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  Stream<List<AttendeeData>> stream1 = Stream.value([
    AttendeeData(name: "John"), AttendeeData(name: "Jane")
  ]);

  Stream<List<AttendeeData>> stream2 = Stream.value([
    AttendeeData(name: "Alice"), AttendeeData(name: "Greg"), AttendeeData(name: "Bryan")
  ]);


  Stream<List<AttendeeData>> merged = Rx.merge([
    stream1,
    stream2
  ]);

  await for(var value in merged) {
    for(var attendee in value) {
      print(attendee.name);
    }
  }
}

# Prints out
# John
# Jane
# Alice
# Greg
# Bryan
```

In your code it would be something like `streamGroup = Rx.merge(listStream)`

Comment: Thanks for the response Matthew.  I actually did move over to combineLatest because I forgot that StreamZip requires both streams to have changes in order to update.  I'm still failing to understand why the Rx solution is required when StreamGroup purports to do the same thing as far as I understand...which is my question. What's my misunderstanding?